# Dart: preventDefault() not working in asynchronous callback when submitting form in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, dart, dart-html

I'm having an issue with `Event.preventDefault()` when submitting a form in IE11. For some reason, it does not prevent the browser from refreshing when using an `async` callback.

HTML:

```
<form id="login">
  <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
  <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

Dart:

```
void main() {
  FormElement form = querySelector('form#login');
  form.onSubmit.listen((Event e) async {
    e.preventDefault();
    // send login request
  });
}
```

If I remove the `async` keyword however, it *does* prevent the browser from refreshing. Am I missing something here, I did not expect it to behave like this? In Chrome it works with and without `async`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an [issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/27884) on the dart-lang/sdk repo on GitHub and it seems that IE11 just executes asynchronous callbacks a bit too late for the `e.preventDefault()` to take effect. So I changed all the callbacks for form submissions to be synchronous so that it is executed right away.

In some scenarios it looked rather messy with `.then()`'s everywhere, so I instead defined an asynchronous function internally so that I could make use of `await`.

Dart:

```
void main() {
  FormElement form = querySelector('form#login');
  form.onSubmit.listen((Event e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    _asyncWrap() async {
      // send login request
    }
    _asyncWrap();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug. Please file it here https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/new and we'll take a look.

Comment: [Created](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/27884). Thanks for your help. Will accept as soon as it is a confirmed bug.